# how to solve Java.lang.StringOutOfBound Exception with SQlitedatabase

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I run the following code and get **Java.lang.StringOutOfBound Exception**

```
   SQLiteDatabase sb;
     String g="o";
    String []gt={"0"};
     try {
        sb=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("data/data/com.example.datatestx/ma", null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);

        sb.execSQL("create table if not exists blac  (" + " phone text  , " + " ftime  text, " + " ttime text );  "    );

        sb.execSQL( "insert into blac(phone, ftime,ttime) values ('01741297133', '333333','33333' );"  );
        sb.execSQL( "insert into blac(phone, ftime,ttime) values ('01761233433', '777' ,'77777');"  );
        sb.execSQL( "insert into blac(phone, ftime,ttime) values ('01712333333', '999','33433' );"  );
        //Cursor c1 = sb.rawQuery( "select * from blac where phone=?", gt);
        String gb="33"; 
        String gh = "SELECT * FROM blac where( phone like '%"+gb+" ')"+"ORDER BY phone";
        Cursor c1 = sb.rawQuery( gh,null);
    if(c1.getCount()>0){

    c1.moveToFirst();
    do {
        g=g+c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("phone"));

    }while(c1.moveToNext());
    }  c1.close();
        sb.close();

         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success!"+g, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();     
    }
```

But after running the code..the value o **g** not changed
please anyone here to help me.

Comment: ...and a little more code please. Your Cursor c1 querys (g,null)..what is g?

Comment: But after running the code..the value of g not changed please anyone here to help me.

Comment: Please, really I beg you: rename your variables to some readable and understandable names. `g`, `c1`, `gt` and `gh`, `gb` and `sb`... do you expect us to make notes what variable represents what?

Comment: Where exactly do you get the exception? You said the value of g did not change. Have you tried, if your query gives any results by System.out.println(...) in loop?

Answer (score 0):

You want to get a String from "phone" Column, but as far I could see, You didn´t creat such a column:

```
    g=g+c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("phone"));
```

If You got String constants for your columns, then You write Your execSQL in the wrong way:

```
    sb.execSQL("create table if not exists blac  (" + " phone text  , " + " ftime  text, " + " ttime text );  "    );
```

You have to write it like this:

```
    sb.execSQL("create table if not exists blac  (" +  phone +" text  , " +  ftime +" text, " +  ttime +" text );  "    );
```